# How to retrieve user without hardcoding ID in discord client.users.get function

Tags: sqlite, discord.js

I'd like my discord bot to send a user (captain) a message, when another user on the server wants to join their team.
I have the DiscordID of the captain stored in my SQLite database and can retrieve it. The problem is that when I pass this variable as an argument to the client.users.get() method, it returns undefined. I've tried converting the DiscordID to a string, but it still returns undefined. When I hardcode the DiscordID it works fine.

I'm not very experienced with discord.js so I'm hoping this is just a trivial issue which can be quickly resolved. Or is this intentionally not possible to avoid bots messaging users without directly receiving a messages from them?

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.users.get('12345'); <-- This returns the user object

const capt = 12345;
client.users.get(capt); <-- returns undefined

const capt = 12345;
const captString = capt.toString();
client.users.get(captString); <-- returns undefined
```

Comment: You *must* use a string. Although `toString()` should work as intended, test with a template literal: ``client.users.get(`${capt}`)``

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although this didn't work either!

Comment: How many numbers are there in the string?

Comment: Storing the DiscordID as a string resolved the issue :)

Comment: If you resolved your Question please use the green tick next to the answers to mark the question as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discord IDs need to be stored as a string**, because  the number is too big for Node.js and would get rounded. By checking `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you'll see that it's less than 18 digits and therefore won't properly store IDs.

Bad: `189855563893571595`
**Good: `'189855563893571595'`**