# Mongoose double = rounds last 2 characters, changing to int64 gives real number back

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When you save `718468316787900476` in a schema with as type `Number`, mongoose saves it as `double`, but it gets saved as `718468316787900400`.

[image: Double rounded]

When I change Double then to `int64` it has that `76` at the end again??

[image: Int64 doesn't round]

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent this?
I need the id to mention a channel in discord, but now I always get undefined when fetching the channel (because the id is invalid)

Comment: your number is too big `console.log(718468316787900476 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)`

Comment: It is a discord id, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: the problem is, the number its too big, you need to store it as an string in your db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201459/how-to-retrieve-user-without-hardcoding-id-in-discord-client-users-get-function